# How to handle events in nested iframe?

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

What I really want to do is to capture the keydown event in iframe and do something else. I search on the Internet but all the materials are about  iframe in a page but what I am faced are iframes in iframe. My code are below and it works well when the iframes are not nested. Can anyone give me some advices?

```
$("iframe").each( function(i) {             
        var currentIframe=this;                     
        $(this).load(function(event) {
            var iFrameDoc =currentIframe.contentDocument || currentIframe.contentWindow.document;                       

            $(iFrameDoc).find("input").each( function(i) {

                $(this).keydown(function(event) {                                   
                  event.stopPropagation();      
                });                     
            });

            $(iFrameDoc).keydown(function(event) {                  
                var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);   
                var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");                
                e.which = code; // # Some key code value    
                $input.trigger(e);  
            }); 

            $(iFrameDoc).mousemove(function(event) {    
                        currentMousePos.x=currentIframe.offsetLeft+event.pageX; 
                        currentMousePos.y=currentIframe.offsetTop+event.pageY;  
            });                         

        });                 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `$("iframe").each()` can get the nested iframe. May be you can code like this `$($("iframe").contentWindow).find("iframe").each(...)`